# AWS DNS service, registering domain

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

As i understand with amazon new route 53 dns service i can host domain names in their servers. but i don't understand where can i register domains (for example .com & .ru etc.) and transfer them to aws service ? (total noob in server configuration)

Answer (score 3):

**edit:** This answer is now outdated since July 31, 2014, when Amazon added domain registration to Route53. http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/07/31/amazon-route-53-announces-domain-name-registration-geo-routing-and-lower-pricing/

Q. Can I register domain names with Amazon Route 53?
    No. Amazon Route 53 does not provide registrar support or integration at this time. For Route 53 to be able to answer DNS queries for your domains, you must inform the registrar you registered your domain name with to update your name server settings, by listing the Route 53 name servers for your hosted zone.

http://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/#Register_domains_with_Route_53

Answer (score 1):

> Q. Can I register domain names with Amazon Route 53?
>
> Yes. You can use the AWS Management Console or API to register new
>   domain names with Route 53. You can also request to transfer in
>   existing domain names from other registrars to be managed by Route 53.
>   Domain name registration services are provided under our Domain Name
>   Registration Agreement.